# Collision between two shape

Tags: java, processing

I was working on an animation on processing.
But, I have a question about the code below:

So, you can see on the output, the ball is going everywhere on the window. I want to make a barrier for the ball. The ball can pass from the `middle` but if it hit the line it goes somewhere with the speed of `(int)random(1, 3)`.

How to make that?
Here is a picture of what I would like to achieve:

Comment: See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html you need to work with vectors etc. You could use Three.js for the math. Note that the intersection of an ellipse is harder to calculate (because the circumference of an ellipse is by definition hard to calculate)

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Can you show on code please?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Actually, as my research I only need one condition, If the line is collision with only one point on the ellipse, but I couldn't implement it.

Comment: Please don't invalidate your question by removing parts from it. I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your toy model, the easiest way to handle collisions is considering a collision zone. So,

1. Establish the collision zone limits x1, x2, y1, y2. When the center of the ball enters this zone, collision rules apply.
2. Consider elastic collisions: your ball only collides with an horizontal line, so only the vertical component of the velocity can be affected, and it never looses speed.
3. Consider to test your toy model with a good bunch of initial conditions, so you can discover any artifacts due to the smallness of your model, the values you are using, and so on. (I have modified the initial position of the ball for a random initial position, run the model several times to see how it behaves under different initial conditions).

```
int dirX = (int)random(1, 3);
int dirY = (int)random(1, 3);
//int x = 20, y = 20;
int middle = 20;

int x = (int)random(20, 180);
int y = (int)random(20, 80);
int x1, x2, y1, y2;

void setup() {
  size(200,200);
  // collision zone limits
  x1 = (width/2 - middle) + 20/2 - 1; // 89
  x2 = (width/2 + middle) - 20/2 + 1; // 111
  y1 = height/2 - 20/2 + 1; // 91
  y2 = height/2 + 20/2 - 1; // 109
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  line(0, height/ 2, width/2 - middle, height/2); // (0, 100, 80, 100)
  line(width/2 + middle, height/2, width, height/2); // (120, 100, 200, 100)
  
  x += dirX;
  y += dirY;

  if (x > width || x < 0)
    dirX *= -1;
  if (y > height || y < 0)
    dirY *= -1;

  if ((x < x1 && y > y1 && y < height/2 && dirY > 0) || // upper left and going down
      (x < x1 && y > height/2 && y < y2 && dirY < 0) || // lower left and going up
      (x > x2 && y > y1 && y < height/2 && dirY > 0) || // upper right and going down
      (x > x2 && y > height/2 && y < y2 && dirY < 0))   // lower right and going up
    dirY *= -1;
}
```

For a more complex model, you could consider more sophisticated situations as, for example, the backwards collision due to the ends of the lines, the collision of the contour of the ball with the lines, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much Laos it was what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to check for collision when the ball passes through the middle, specifically when the ball's velocity would make y pass from < height/2 to > height/2.

Something like this:

```
if (((y < height/2 && y+dirY > height/2) || (y > height/2 && y+dirY < height/2)) && (x < width/2-middle || x > width/2+middle)){
   dirY = (int) random (1,3);
   dirX = (int) random (1,3);
}
```

(A more appropriate solution would be to create the collision when the edge of the ball passes the barrier, but I'll leave that up to you)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried it but couldn't help. I guess I need using this link:`mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html`. Do you know how to implement it?

Comment: As my research I only need one condition, If the line is collision with only one point on the ellipse, but I couldn't implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to write code, but I'll tell you how to calculate it, it's not that hard.

Taken a circle, we know the center and the radius.

Taken a line we know the startpoint and endpoint.

1. The line intersects the circle if the distance from them `center` to `startpoint` or `endpoint` is smaller than `radius` (e.g. point is inside circle)
2. A line intersects circle if `startpoint` X is on the left of center (sX < cX), `endpoint` X on the right (eX > cX), and the distance between their Y and the `center` Y is less than `radius` (cY - sY < r)

Note that this really applies only in your simple case with a horizontal line. Normally is better to really work with vectors calculations to determine distance from center to line for example. That would allow you to work with diagonal lines etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I couldn't understand the second one.

Comment: The second one is the situation of your second image, where we calculate a collision of the circle with a line segment, where the start and endpoints of that segment are not inside the circle.

Comment: For the first one should I calculate the distance between the startpoint and end point of line?

Comment: As I should use `dist()` for the distance between radius of circle and line coordinates but I don't know which coordinate should I choose for the line.

Comment: You need to check both. If one of the points is inside circle, you have a collision.